# Can you have a dynamic collection for ng-repeat in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the ng-repeat directive used in my code, but I want to have the dynamic collection inside the same. It looks like this:

```
<tr md-row ng-repeat="agentData in verticalAgents.ALLAgents">
    <td md-cell>{{ agentData['username'] }}</td>
</tr>
```

I was wondering of I could make the ng-repeat look like this:

```
<ng-repeat="agentData in verticalAgents.{{verticalAgents.Tab}}">
```

where `verticalAgents.Tab` is dynamic. I know this is not possible, but what can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Just use the same notation as you do in `agentData['username']`:

```
<tr md-row 
    ng-repeat="agentData in verticalAgents[verticalAgents.Tab]">
    <!-- ... -->
</tr>
```

Comment: I used the logic behind this. Thank you very much :)